# Voice recognition in java using freets

Tags: java, voice-recognition, freetts

Is there any way to write a program of voice recognition in Java?

I understood that there are many technologies, and I found freetts which seems to be a comfortable one, though I succeeded to write a program of text-to-speech, but didn't find any reference of voice recognition with it.

Does anyone have references for me on that matter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: text-to-speech is not speech-to-text. A web search for "speech recognition java" returns lots of results. So does "voice recognition java".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FreeTTS does not support speech recognition (as far as I know) - it is only implemented to support text-to-speech.

So you will need to use some other tool for speech recognition.

You can have a look at Sphinx which is a speech recognition tool written in Java which I had used for my university project.

Check this link to learn more about [Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/)

You will require some tweaking with Sphinx to suit you requirements - which is easier than creating your own speech recognition engine.

You can refer this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSnjlmfkrG0) for a short tutorial on Sphinx.

Comment: Is there any documentation, too?

Comment: There is documentation also, but not sure about the depth of the details

Comment: +1.  For _instead of finding a speech recognition engine and ending up in having nothing more useful than Sphinx 4_